# Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notification for set of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app using Firebase, in the app there are groups and for groups there are multiple members. I want to send notifications to members in a particular group based on one of the users activity. As an example in a chat app, notification to others informing there is a new message.

I referred [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). As it seems best way to do this is Firebase Topic Messaging, all members can be subscribed to the group id as a topic.

**My matter** is how to avoid receiving notification to the member who's action causes to the notification.

I tried Firebase message sending to multiple topics but it only allows for two logical operations (&&, ||)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has two types of messages: notification messages and data messages.

The default behavior of Firebase is that *notification messages* will automatically be displayed if the app is in the background or not running. This behavior cannot be modified. If the app is in the foreground, the notification message will not be automatically shown, it will instead be delivered to your app's code.

Data messages on the other hand will always be delivered to your app's code.

Since the user sending the message will typically have the app open, the default behavior will automatically ensure the notification is not shown on the sending user's device.

But in the blog post you refer to there is a race condition for this. If the user closes the app between the time they send the notification to the server and the time the server sends out the notification, the notification may show on their device too.

If this is a concern for your app, you should not use a notification message. Use a data message instead and include enough information in the message to detect which user has sent it (e.g. the user's uid).

Comment: Thanks Puffelen for the quick response. My concern is it, if user closes app, notification will show on that device.

Comment: BTW there is a way if Firebase multiple topics condition supports for the !(NOT) operation also. A user can be subscribed under his uid and group id. Then we can write a condition `'group_id' in topics && !('user_id' in topics)`